# obtain customer_id automatically on new record

Tags: delphi

I am pulling down records with a stored procedure of customers that have a customer_id=5.

Now the procedure gets the data and shows it in the grid and I want to add a new record .
How can I make sure that when I add new record in the grid it has automatically the same customer_id ( 5 ) ?

I dont want to write it down all the time.I used to know this but I forgot.The DB is sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [**DefaultExpression**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.DefaultExpression) to the used ID for the field you want. For example for a UniDAC stored procedure object you can do (**ParamCustID** is the procedure input parameter, **FieldCustID** is the returned dataset field name):

```
var
  CustID: Integer;
begin
  CustID := 123;

  UniStoredProc1.StoredProcName := 'MyProcedure';
  UniStoredProc1.PrepareSQL;
  UniStoredProc1.ParamByName('ParamCustID').AsInteger := CustID;
  UniStoredProc1.Execute;

  UniStoredProc1.FieldByName('FieldCustID').ReadOnly := True;
  UniStoredProc1.FieldByName('FieldCustID').DefaultExpression := IntToStr(CustID);
end;
```

The above code will setup the field for assigning same value for every appended tuple, and makes it read only. Out of curiosity, the same task for FireDAC would go like this (for applying changes, there must be an explicit method call for updating field attributes):

```
var
  CustID: Integer;
begin
  CustID := 123;

  FDStoredProc1.StoredProcName := 'MyProcedure';
  FDStoredProc1.Prepare;
  FDStoredProc1.ParamByName('@ParamCustID').AsInteger := CustID;
  FDStoredProc1.Open;

  FDStoredProc1.FieldByName('FieldCustID').ReadOnly := True;
  FDStoredProc1.FieldByName('FieldCustID').DefaultExpression := IntToStr(CustID);

  FDStoredProc1.UpdateAttributes;
end;
```

Comment: You can of course assign `DefaultExpression` value from a certain tuple field value as well (if they are same, it can be any of them). The above example is just what I imagined that you do.

Comment: when I said I am pulling data by customer_id that means  customer_id can also change. I know I can set default value but that's not it. I want new records to be added with customer_id I am actually seeing in the grid.

Comment: Well, this is it, then. If you can see (or not, it's not necessary to be displayed) in a grid in certain column only one same value and you want to set this value when appending a new tuple (and keep it unchanged), you'd do what is shown here.